# Split a string in a cell in Excel using numbers as the divider

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Example cell value: President & Founder, Millennium Pain Center, 1998– present.

I'd want that parsed (split) into "President & Founder, Millennium Pain Center," and in another cell, " 1998– present."

Is this doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doable with an array formula. Here's a solution based on [an algorithm](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/extracting-numbers-from-alphanumeric-strings-HA001154901.aspx) on the MS Office website. I modified the formula to take *string length* into consideration so that you can use it with other phrases.

Assuming A1 contains your string ("President & Founder, Millennium Pain Center, 1998– present"), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> this in **B1**:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$"&LEN(A1))),1)),0)
```

It will return the index of the first number that occurs in the string. For the example, it will return 46.

Enter this (as a normal formula) in **C1**:

```
=MID(A1,1,B1-1)
```

It will return *President & Founder, Millennium Pain Center,*

Enter this (as a normal formula) in **D1**:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-B1+1)
```

It will return *1998– present*

[image]

Comment: Good Catch on the variable length parameter.

Comment: How do I Ctrl + Shift + Enter? I just press them, then release, then press CTRL + V?

Comment: First, copy the formula, then paste it into the formula bar. Instead of pressing `Enter` like you normally do when entering data, press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` altogether.

Comment: OK... After pressing that, I still don't get anything other than a #N/A

Comment: After pressing those keys, the formula should get enclosed in braces ("{ }"). That's how you can tell it's been entered as an array formula.

Comment: OK... I wasn't pressing <Ctrl> + <Shift> + <Enter> while inside the cell... I just had the cell selected.

Answer (score 6):

These will work, they are array formulas, so you must use **CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER** when you enter them in the cell.  The number $40 just needs to be big enough for your largest string:

```
=LEFT(A1, MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1, ROW($1:$40), 1)),0)-1)
```

and

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1, ROW($1:$40), 1)),0) +1)
```

The MID statement is creating an array of all the characters in the string.
The ISNUMBER statement then turns that into a TRUE/FALSE array.
The MATCH statement then finds the first TRUE, so therefore the first number.
Then it's just a matter of parsing.

Comment: I'm getting a #N/A error.

I don't know how to make this work. Assuming the line I want to parse, is in A1.  Where does the =LEFT and = RIGHT go?  How can I then parse in Excel?

Comment: The =LEFT is for the left side of the split you want, so put it in that cell.  The =RIGHT is for the right side of the split you want, so put it in that cell.  My formula does the parsing, I was just explaining.

Comment: I took a [screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CN6mn.png)... then tried to have them execute.  looked like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CN6mn.png)
Why?

Comment: @wizlog, you put the same picture both times in the link so I can't see the result, but realize you're using Kaze's method, and I only tested with mine.

Comment: Sorry. When you say "that cell" where (exactly)?

Comment: @wizlog, now your confusing me, in your question you talked about the split you wanted, and referenced "and in another cell", so I assumed you had cells that you wanted your values in.  I have no idea where you want those cells.

Comment: Thanks for your second formula Lance, i'm using it as the basis for something similar in my own Excel related question at (http://superuser.com/questions/366318/excel-2010-formula-to-strip-out-part-of-cells)